# Filesystem fuse slow

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I purchased a *Maxtor M3 external HDD 4TB, 2,5'*.

The filesystem is of type `fuse`.

I need to use this HDD only for backup purpose, by copying manually the files about few times a months (average 10 GB for months) from Ubuntu and read if from Ubuntu (there can be a very remote case I need to read it from windows).

I noticed that the copy of files from tower PC with USB `2.0` is slower than an older `HDD` with a different filesystem.

I don't know the characteristics of a `fuse` filesystem, should I maintain it or format it with another filesystem?

And why?

Thanks

Comment: "fuse" is not a filesystem. It's a bridge to a real filesystem. I would bet the true filesystem is NTFS. Fuse will create a virtual "view" of that NTFS partition giving it what would appear to be Linux ownership and permissions.

AN NTFS partition in Linux would in fact run slower than a native Linux filesystem. It would run slower than the same NTFS partition in Windows. All because of this fuse "bridge". Not much you can do about it if you want compatibility with Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please post it as an answer so I'll can accept it. It seems nobody want the bounty...

Comment: @user2342558 You blame the "fuse" file system, but the narrower bottleneck might well be the fact that you use USB2, which has a limited sped as of today's standards,  480 megabits per second (think 48 megabytes/sec approx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"fuse" is not a filesystem. It's a bridge to a real filesystem. I would bet the true filesystem is NTFS. Fuse will create a virtual "view" of that NTFS partition giving it what would appear to be Linux ownership and permissions. AN NTFS partition in Linux would in fact run slower than a native Linux filesystem. It would run slower than the same NTFS partition in Windows. All because of this fuse "bridge". Not much you can do about it if you want compatibility with Windows